# Script to update AD description and computer description

Tags: powershell

What i want to create is a powershell script with a GUI that will update the computer descriptions and mirror the description in AD. For example if i were to type in a computer name like "PC-Hallway" and update its description to "location Hallway"  then the info would populate in AD and the PC description field. I have something really close to what i want attached but cant get it to pass the information that gets typed into the fields to the "set-adcomputer" or the "-description".

```
function button ($title,$mailbx, $WF, $TF) {


[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( “System.Windows.Forms”)
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( “Microsoft.VisualBasic”)

$form = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Form”;
$form.Width = 500;
$form.Height = 150;
$form.Text = $title;
$form.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen;

$textLabel1 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Label”;
$textLabel1.Left = 25;
$textLabel1.Top = 15;

$textLabel1.Text = $mailbx;



$textLabel2 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Label”;
$textLabel2.Left = 25;
$textLabel2.Top = 50;

$textLabel2.Text = $WF;



$textLabel3 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Label”;
$textLabel3.Left = 25;
$textLabel3.Top = 85;

$textLabel3.Text = $TF;

$textBox1 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.TextBox”;
$textBox1.Left = 150;
$textBox1.Top = 10;
$textBox1.width = 200;


$textBox2 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.TextBox”;
$textBox2.Left = 150;
$textBox2.Top = 50;
$textBox2.width = 200;


$button = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Button”;
$button.Left = 360;
$button.Top = 85;
$button.Width = 100;
$button.Text = “Ok”;


$eventHandler = [System.EventHandler]{
$textBox1.Text;
$textBox2.Text;
$textBox3.Text;
$form.Close();};

$button.Add_Click($eventHandler) ;

$form.Controls.Add($button);
$form.Controls.Add($textLabel1);
$form.Controls.Add($textLabel2);
$form.Controls.Add($textLabel3);
$form.Controls.Add($textBox1);
$form.Controls.Add($textBox2);
$ret = $form.ShowDialog();


return $textBox1.Text, $textBox2.txt
}

$return= button “Computer info” “Enter Asset info” “Asset location”


$return[0]
$return[1]
$return[2]

set-adcomputer $return[1] -description $return[2]
$mydescription = $return[2]
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $return[1] -ScriptBlock {$OSWMI=getwmiobject -class win32_operatingsystem;$OSWMI.description=$args[0];$OSWMI.put() } -ArgumentList($mydescription)
```

Comment: How is this related to batch files?

Comment: Why are you write a GUI for this simple task? Even if you wanted to use a GUI, you could avoid all the from code, and use the Powershell Help System to create a simple GUI. [PoorMan's GUI](https://powershell.getchell.org/2018/02/13/poor-mans-gui/). Your code is broken, you have elements you are not using, etc., you capture info in the variable and pass it on.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to indicate you are new to GUI design. That's finer and all, but really you should get some training on the topic. [Youtube is your friend.](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=create%20powershell%20gui)

You collect the info from your form ...

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$ComputerName = 'SomeCurrentHostName'
$Location     = 'NA/HQ/Building A'
$Description  = 'I am a Windows 10 Computer'
Set-ADComputer -Identity $ComputerName -Location $Location  -Description $Description
```

and pass that on the click event of the button.

It's more prudent to create a function to test, fully test it, then assign that function to the button click event. This way your GUI code and code-behind are separate and the code behind.

For example, a refactor of what you show would be something like the below. Note, I am only outputting this to the screen as a demo showing the value captures from the form. There is really no reason to output to the screen.

```
###############################################################################
#region Begin initialize environment                                          #
###############################################################################

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

###############################################################################
#endregion End initialize environment                                         #
###############################################################################


###############################################################################
#region Begin Code library                                                    #
###############################################################################

Function Update-ComputerDetails
{
    Write-Host $txtNewComputerName.Text
    Write-Host $txtNewComputerLocation.Text
    Write-Host $txtNewComputerDescription.Text

<#
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory

    $paramblock = @{
        Identity    = $txtNewComputerName.Text
        Location    = $txtNewComputerLocation.Text
        Description = $txtNewComputerDescription.Text
    }

    Set-ADComputer @paramblock
#>

}


Function Exit-ComputerDetails
{
    $frmComputerInfo.Close()
}

###############################################################################
#endregion End Code library                                                   #
###############################################################################


###############################################################################
#region Begin GUI code                                                        #
###############################################################################

$frmComputerInfo                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$frmComputerInfo.ClientSize            = '489,157'
$frmComputerInfo.text                  = "Update Active Directory Computer Information"
$frmComputerInfo.TopMost               = $false

$lblNewComputerName                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$lblNewComputerName.text               = "New Computer Name"
$lblNewComputerName.AutoSize           = $true
$lblNewComputerName.width              = 25
$lblNewComputerName.height             = 10
$lblNewComputerName.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(36,34)
$lblNewComputerName.Font               = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$txtNewComputerName                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$txtNewComputerName.multiline          = $false
$txtNewComputerName.width              = 253
$txtNewComputerName.height             = 20
$txtNewComputerName.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(189,29)
$txtNewComputerName.Font               = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$lblNewComputerLocation                = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$lblNewComputerLocation.text           = "New Computer Location"
$lblNewComputerLocation.AutoSize       = $true
$lblNewComputerLocation.width          = 25
$lblNewComputerLocation.height         = 10
$lblNewComputerLocation.location       = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(36,58)
$lblNewComputerLocation.Font           = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$txtNewComputerLocation                = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$txtNewComputerLocation.multiline      = $false
$txtNewComputerLocation.width          = 252
$txtNewComputerLocation.height         = 20
$txtNewComputerLocation.location       = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(189,55)
$txtNewComputerLocation.Font           = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$lblNewComputerDescription             = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$lblNewComputerDescription.text        = "New Description"
$lblNewComputerDescription.AutoSize    = $true
$lblNewComputerDescription.width       = 25
$lblNewComputerDescription.height      = 10
$lblNewComputerDescription.location    = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(36,85)
$lblNewComputerDescription.Font        = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$txtNewComputerDescription             = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$txtNewComputerDescription.multiline   = $false
$txtNewComputerDescription.width       = 252
$txtNewComputerDescription.height      = 20
$txtNewComputerDescription.location    = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(189,79)
$txtNewComputerDescription.Font        = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$btnOK                                 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$btnOK.text                            = "OK"
$btnOK.width                           = 60
$btnOK.height                          = 30
$btnOK.location                        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(306,107)
$btnOK.Font                            = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$btnCancel                             = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$btnCancel.text                        = "Cancel"
$btnCancel.width                       = 60
$btnCancel.height                      = 30
$btnCancel.location                    = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(379,107)
$btnCancel.Font                        = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$frmComputerInfo.controls.AddRange(@(
    $lblNewComputerName,
    $txtNewComputerName,
    $lblNewComputerLocation,
    $txtNewComputerLocation,
    $lblNewComputerDescription,
    $txtNewComputerDescription,
    $btnOK,
    $btnCancel
    )
)

###############################################################################
#endregion End GUI code                                                       #
###############################################################################


###############################################################################
#region Begin logic execution code                                            #
###############################################################################

$btnOK.Add_Click({ Update-ComputerDetails })
$btnCancel.Add_Click({ Exit-ComputerDetails })
[void]$frmComputerInfo.ShowDialog()

###############################################################################
#endregion End Logic execution code                                           #
###############################################################################
```

Or even more direct and simplified this way:

```
# Custom Input Box

#region Begin environment initialization
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
#endregion

#region Begin GUI code
$form                      = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text                 = 'Data Entry Form'
$form.Size                 = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size(300, 200)
$form.StartPosition        = 'CenterScreen'

$label                     = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location            = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size(10, 20)
$label.Size                = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size(280, 25)
$label.Text                = 'Please enter the computername, location name, and description information in the spaces below'

$textBox1                  = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox1.Location         = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size(13, 50)
$textBox1.Size             = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size(260, 20)

$textBox2                  = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox2.Location         = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size(13, 70)
$textBox2.Size             = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size(260, 20)

$textBox3                  = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox3.Location         = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size(13, 90)
$textBox3.Size             = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size(260, 20)

$OkButton                  = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OkButton.Location         = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size(75, 120)
$OkButton.Size             = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
$OkButton.Text             = 'OK'
$OkButton.DialogResult     = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK

$CancelButton              = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location     = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size(150, 120)
$CancelButton.Size         = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
$CancelButton.Text         = 'Cancel'
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel

$form.Controls.AddRange(@(
        $label,
        $textBox1,
        $textBox2,
        $textBox3,
        $OkButton,
        $CancelButton
    )
)

$form.add_Shown({$textBox.Select()})
#endregion

# Beging GUI presentation
$form.TopMost      = $true
$form.AcceptButton = $OkButton
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
#endregion

#region Begin logic execution
$result = $form.ShowDialog()


If ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $textBox1.Text
    $textBox2.Text
    $textBox3.Text
}
Else{'Cancel was pressed. Application Exited.'}
#endregion
```

There several pre-built scripts to do what you are after, without the need for GUI. See these:

> [Powershell script to set AD Computer description during OSD](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Powershell-script-to-set-9fc067af) --- [Download: SetComputerDesc.zip](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Powershell-script-to-set-9fc067af/file/195044/1/SetComputerDesc.zip)
>
> [Update Computer Description–PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/6e883230-fa47-4a9e-aa92-446ab3bea6dd) --- [Download: Update_Comptuer_Description.txt](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/6e883230-fa47-4a9e-aa92-446ab3bea6dd/file/44639/1/Update_Comptuer_Description.txt)
>
> [How to rename a domain computer with Windows PowerShell](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/data-center/how-to-rename-a-domain-computer-with-windows-powershell)

***Update***

BTW, that OGV I speak to in the comment is just something like this: 
(no, not very pretty - but usable).

```
Start-Process -FilePath (
    Get-ChildItem -Path 'd:\scripts' -Filter '*.ps1' | 
    Sort-Object -Property Name | 
    Out-GridView -Title 'Select a script to run' -OutputMode Single
).FullName -Wait
```

There are ways to nest OGV responses to get a flow of results as well. See this:

> [Creating a Simplistic GUI Interface with Out-GridView](https://mikefrobbins.com/2014/09/11/creating-a-simplistic-gui-interface-with-out-gridview/)
>   and this...
>   [How To Use Out-Gridview As A GUI In PowerShell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l7DDM4lPUQY)

Comment: Thank you for the advice and the info. I really appreciate it. Yes, i am relatively new to powershell and most of the PS scripts ive written were because of youtube and other sources on the web. I wanted to create a GUI for this task (and others in the future) because employees that come into my office have little to no PS experiance.  Its quick and easy for them to click an icon update the info and be done.  If all this work was done by myself id have no problem with the default way of doing PS scripts.

Comment: No worries, but creating GUI for every script is really not something you should need to do. Create a script library, and leverage Out-GridView to preset a list of scripts for your users to select and run. So, one simple no maintenance UI. You create a shortcut on the users desktop to run the startup script and let your script do its thing. Just name your scritps for the purpose intended, use Get-ChildItem to read that folder and send to Out-Grid view for them to select from, all input would just be console prompt stuff.

Comment: Also, if this addresses your use case, remember to mark this as your accepted answer for the benefit of others who find themselves in the same need.